# Pyscript > Source Py > reading a csv file is not working

Tags: python, html, csv, file-upload, pyscript

I am new to Python/pyscript/html. I want to create an interactive dashboard using Python, based on csv/text or json files which are on my local drive. The HTML file works and I am able to access it via localhost.

The issue I have is with this part: `<py-script src="test.py">  </py-script>`

If the test.py contains `print(test)` it will print test. But if the test.py contains `df = pd.read_csv(r'U:\df.csv', sep='\t')` it doesn't work. Even though the py works in a normal python environment.

The error code is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: 'U:\\df.json'`. I noticed that it creates another backslash. I have changed the location of the file, but nothing seems to work.

I even added the logic straight into the py-script, but this does not work either.

```html
    <body>
        <py-script >
        import pandas as pd
        Output12 = pd.read_csv(r'U:\Project\df.csv', sep='\t') </py-script>
    </body>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you open the file directly in the browser (by e.g. double-clicking it in Explorer) or do you serve it with an HTTP server (so that the address is `http://localhost`)?

Comment: Opening the file via http://localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PyScript (or any system using the Pyodide runtime) accesses files with something like `with open(...)`, the filesystem it's accessing is the virtual, in-memory filesystem that that [Emscripten wraps a program with at compilation time](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html), not your local filesystem. This filesystem is reset/bootstrapped from scratch each time the page loads, and lives in the Browser tab's memory.

To load files into the virtual filesystem, PyScript provides a feature of the <py-config> tag called [[[fetch]] configurations](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html#a-name-fetch-fetch-a). A fetch configuration contains a `files` key, which is a list of files to load into the current working directory of the file system (the same folder py-script tags run in).

Assuming that your localhost server uses `D:/project` as the root, you can load into the virtual file system like so:

```html
<body>
    <py-config>
        [[fetch]]
        files = ['df.csv'] # This is a relative URL; you can also use a fully qualified URL
    </py-config>
    <py-script >
        import pandas as pd
        Output12 = pd.read_csv('df.csv', sep='\t')
    </py-script>
</body>
```

A `[[fetch]]` configuration can take several additional keys, including `from` for introducing a general prefix to all the fetched file paths, `to_file` for specifying a filename that's different from the file being loaded, and `to_folder` for specifying a different folder in the virtual filesystem to load to. See the linked docs above for more info and examples.